# Navigation bar flickering when over scroll in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

When overscroll up the transition between inline and large navigation is not smooth and there is a short flickering

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

      NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                Text("Content")
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 300)
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"), displayMode: .large)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you also experience this on a device? Have you tried installing the app on an IPhone? If so, id highly assume that this is some sort of bug that you would need to report to Apple.